# Publish to a blog from an application

Tags: c#, blogs, publish

I have an application which I need to add the ability to publish to a blog.  It doesn't need to publish anything fancy, just a subject, post, author, and perhaps tags, etc.

Currently the blog engine I am focusing on is BlogEngine.NET.  I can get the information about the blog from the asd file, but I am not sure how to actually send a new blog post.

This functionality will most probably be extended to other blog engines in the future.  I have never written something like this before so I am not sure if posting to blogs will be different for each engine or if they have some type of similarities.

The application is written in C# (.NET 4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to post to most of these blog engines with ATOM api (atompub) http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1303
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(standard)